# UISearchBar Search icon overlay on background iOS

Tags: ios, iphone, search, uisearchbar

Search icon on `UISearchBar` is overlay on background of `UISearchBar` on normal state.
[image]

When i am starting Editing, its display perfect. see attached image. 
[image]

I want to display search icon like below.
[image]

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I had found that its not possible through native `UISearchBar` control, we must develop custom SearchBar using `UITextField`.

We need to use `UITextFieldDelegate` with `UITextField`.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote an extension for UISearchBar, for its customisation. 
Refer this link: https://github.com/Rakshith-Nandish/SearchBarCustomiser

Usage:

```
yourSearchBarInstance.setCancelButtonColor(color: UIColor.black)
       yourSearchBarInstance.becomeFirstResponder()
```

not setting it to first responder does not change the color of the 'Cancel' button. Hope this helps